# SIGSEGV error in some lua/c++ code

Tags: c++, lua, segmentation-fault

The following code end in a SIGSEGV error:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "lua/lua.h"
    #include "lua/lualib.h"
    #include "lua/lauxlib.h"
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    lua_State *L;
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

Gdb gives me the following:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: d:\Dropbox\cpp\engine\bin\main.exe
[New Thread 7008.0x1df8]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x6d781f30 in lua_pushcclosure () from d:\Dropbox\cpp\engine\bin\lua52.dll
(gdb) where
#0  0x6d781f30 in lua_pushcclosure () from d:\Dropbox\cpp\engine\bin\lua52.dll
#1  0x6d79329e in luaL_requiref () from d:\Dropbox\cpp\engine\bin\lua52.dll
#2  0x6d79bdee in luaL_openlibs () from d:\Dropbox\cpp\engine\bin\lua52.dll
#3  0x004013a6 in main (argc=1, argv=0x702fc8) at main.cpp:10
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to do create a new lua state before opening the lib (`luaL_openlibs(L);`), like this:

```
L = luaL_newstate();
```

You get the segmentation fault because you have an unitialized pointer, dereferencing it (which is what the lib does) is undefined behavior.

Comment: Technically, this is not a pointer to nothing, this is an un-initialised pointer, and this cause undefined behaviour (here a segmentation fault) when dereferenced.

Comment: I was trying to simplify the code and ended up deleting the luaL_newstate without noticing it. Thanks. I think I'm to tired to work atm.