# Lua C API Memory Leak? (valgrind)

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, lua, valgrind

I'm trying to write a C program with Lua embedded inside.. And, I tried a very simple program to start, it just creates the Lua context, and then destroys it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
extern "C" {
    #include <lua.h>
    #include <lauxlib.h>
    #include <lualib.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    lua_State *L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_close(L);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return(0);
}
```

I'm compiling it like so: (I'm actually using Torch7, so..)

```
g++ -c -g3 -O2 -Wall -Werror -I/usr/local/torch/install/include/ -fPIC pure_lua_test.C -o pure_lua_test.o
g++ -g3 -O2 -Wall -Werror -I/usr/local/torch/install/include/ -fPIC -o pure_lua_test pure_lua_test.o -L/usr/local/torch/install/lib/ -lluajit
```

When I run it on it's own, it prints

```
pure_lua_test.C: 16
```

as expected, (just before the return).

But, when I run it with valgrind, (as valgrind ./pure_lua_test )

I get

```
==9165== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9165== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9165== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9165== Command: ./pure_lua_test
==9165== 
==9165== Invalid read of size 4
==9165==    at 0x4E9EE97: lua_pushcclosure (in /usr/local/src/torch-2015-05-25/install/lib/libluajit.so)
==9165==    by 0x4EB4CDD: luaL_openlibs (in /usr/local/src/torch-2015-05-25/install/lib/libluajit.so)
==9165==    by 0x400700: main (pure_lua_test.C:13)
==9165==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==9165== 
==9165== 
==9165== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==9165==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
==9165==    at 0x4E9EE97: lua_pushcclosure (in /usr/local/src/torch-2015-05-25/install/lib/libluajit.so)
==9165==    by 0x4EB4CDD: luaL_openlibs (in /usr/local/src/torch-2015-05-25/install/lib/libluajit.so)
==9165==    by 0x400700: main (pure_lua_test.C:13)
==9165==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==9165==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==9165==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==9165==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==9165==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==9165== 
==9165== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9165==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9165==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==9165== 
==9165== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9165== 
==9165== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9165== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Does anyone know what's happening? Why is it SIGSEGV'ing in valgrind? Is this something I should worry about? Basically, I was hoping to verify that a plugin I was writing for Torch had no memory leaks... But, if it fails with this, then, I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: I tried changing the lua_open() to luaL_newstate(), but I still get the same problem with valgrind..

Comment: Does this fix your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840569/sigsegv-error-in-some-lua-c-code

Comment: LuaJIT needs to be compiled with Valgrind support. Search the LuaJIT Makefile (in the `src` sub-directory) for `LUAJIT_USE_VALGRIND`.

Comment: Interesting. The Makefile has... seemingly contradictory information about whether or not I can use it on x64:

# Use the system provided memory allocator (realloc) instead of the
# bundled memory allocator. This is slower, but sometimes helpful for
# debugging. This option cannot be enabled on x64, since realloc usually
# doesn't return addresses in the right address range.
# OTOH this option is mandatory for Valgrind's memcheck tool on x64 and
# the only way to get useful results from it for all other architectures.
#XCFLAGS+= -DLUAJIT_USE_SYSMALLOC

(Just before the -DLUAJIT_USE_VALGRIND)

Comment: Although... Even when I add that, and make clean, etc, and recompile, I _still_ get the SIGSEGV... But, given that it seems clear that LuaJIT must be doing some black magic to accomplish what it does, I'm willing to live with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this issue seems to be Valgrind, not LuaJIT. Valgrind is [blocking MAP_32BIT which breaks LuaJIT](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.lua.luajit/4826). To demonstrate, add a check for `NULL` on `lua_State * L` and you'll see it is NULL while run under Valgrind, and non-`NULL` while running regularly.

Here is the modifications I did to your sample:

```c
if(L == NULL) {
    printf("Could not create luaL_newstate()\n");
} else {
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_close(L);
    printf("I can create luaL_newstate fine!\n");
}
```

When I run this normally:

```
$ ./pure_lua_test 
I can create luaL_newstate fine!
```

But when I run it under Valgrind:

```
$ valgrind ./pure_lua_test
==8211== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8211== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8211== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8211== Command: ./pure_lua_test
==8211== 
Could not create luaL_newstate()
==8211==
```

GDB also report that the application exited as it should:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/pure_lua_test 
I can create luaL_newstate fine!
[Inferior 1 (process 8621) exited normally]
```

Here is a complete MCVE:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
extern "C" {
        #include <lua.h>
        #include <lauxlib.h>
        #include <lualib.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();

    if(L == NULL) {
        printf("Could not create luaL_newstate()\n");
    } else {
        luaL_openlibs(L);

        lua_close(L);
        printf("I can create luaL_newstate fine!\n");
    }

    return(0);
}
```

[Here](https://lwn.net/Articles/294642/) is a nice article on MAP_32BIT. Hope this helps in any way.

Comment: The problem seems corrected for the version 3.11.0.